# GetTempPathA how would I know size in advance?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode, ansi

I am coding in C, using the Windows API.

I was looking at the **GetTempPathA()** function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha), and have included the function's syntax below.

```
DWORD GetTempPathA(
  DWORD nBufferLength,
  LPSTR lpBuffer
);
```

I can see the path will be stored in lpBuffer, but I could not understand how I am expected to know what size to set the DWORD nBufferLength to - I expect people with more Windows development experience will tell me it is one value for ANSI language systems and another for Unicode, but I would rather ask the professionals here on Stackoverflow for guidance?

I would assume it needs to be set to the longest value possible for a file path, as perhaps the user somehow changed the default location to a longer path elsewhere on the system, but I am only guessing.

This appears to be just an ANSI function, however during my time looking over the documentation on MSDN I often find functions which have an ANSI and Unicode function (which end in A and W respectively). I do understand the difference between them, but if I had to create a buffer what would the maximum input size be?

Lastly, when answering please keep in mind that I do enjoy writing backwards compatible applications, as many of my friends live in third world countries without access to the latest Windows operating systems.

Comment: Why are you using the ANSI version rather than the Unicode version of this function?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On MSDN it appeared only to have an ANSI version, and I want backwards compatibility. This ANSI version works on older OS, and at the cost of resources the ANSI is converted to Unicode on newer OS.

Comment: You aren't running your code on Windows 98. Look again at the docs, there is a Unicode version, of course. And Windows is implemented using Unicode so when you call an ANSI function, that is more expensive in terms of conversion. Don't use ANSI versions. Use Unicode.

Comment: @questioner Google usually displays the ANSI version when searching the function name. If there's an A behind the function name, there's always a UNICODE version

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want a single executable to work from Windows 98 to Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and 10. This means I have to use the ANSI version, and let the end user suffer with a performance hit during the conversion. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: I don't believe to do want to support Windows 98. I can't believe that you have a Windows 98 installation to test on, and if you did you'd find that your program does not run on it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do want to support Windows 98, and I have a virtual machine with it installed for testing. It is possible that the GetTempPath() function is not available on Windows 98, only testing will tell. I am well aware of other compatibility problems, like ensuring my program links to msvct.dll instead of msvcr*.dll where you replace * with a version number.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am doing this for fun. I have already run hello world programs on Windows 98, compiled with Visual Studio 2010. The trick is to link to msvcrt.dll instead of msvcr100.dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a *fixed-size* buffer that will hold the maximum possible path length (e.g. `char buffer[MAX_PATH+1];`) or, if you want to allocate *just enough*  buffer space, call the `GetTempPathA` function initially with a `nBufferLength` argument of zero and a `NULL` value for `lpBuffer`. (The latter is not fully documented, from what I can see, but the code below works and that system is used for many other WinAPI calls that require a buffer of a given size.)

Test code:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD answer = GetTempPathA(0, NULL);
    printf("%lu\n", answer);
    char* buffer = malloc(answer);
    answer = GetTempPathA(answer, buffer);
    printf("Temp path is: >>>%s<<< (length = %lu)\n", buffer, answer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the value of `answer` in the first call will be one greater than in the second call (because the former will include room for the `nul` terminator).

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha):

> #### Return Value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in TCHARs, of the string copied to lpBuffer, not including
> the terminating null character. If the return value is greater than
> nBufferLength, the return value is the length, in TCHARs, of the
> buffer required to hold the path.

Or, for a version that works 'generically', for both Unicode and multi-byte (ANSI) builds, use the following:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD answer = GetTempPath(0, NULL);
    _tprintf(TEXT("%lu\n"), answer);
    TCHAR* buffer = malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * answer);
    answer = GetTempPath(answer, buffer);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Temp path is: >>>%s<<< (length = %lu)\n"), buffer, answer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to perform adequate error handling in production code - check the return value of `GetTempPath()` for 0, check the return value of `malloc()` for NULL, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. I left out those checks for the sake of brevity, but maybe I *should* include them?

Answer (score 2):

MSDN clearly states that usually maximum path length is 260 characters:

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
> paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
> defined as 260 characters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

The article also states that application can opt-in into long paths through manifests, starting from certain Windows versions.

Comment: I have heard that newer versions of Windows allow for paths that surpass 260 characters though. Also, if I go with 260 characters, should I do 260 * 8 = 2080 for the DWORD size?

Comment: @questioner the link I provided addresses newer Windows versions. No, you do not need to multiply anything. DWORD is the type of the argument (basically, long int).

Comment: DWORD nBufferLength = 260; This is sufficient for my program?

Comment: @questioner well, you also have to actually prepare a buffer of at least this length.

Comment: @questioner if you don't opt-in to the newer long-path behavior, then the path cannot exceed 260 characters (use the `MAX_PATH` define, don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your code). If you do opt-in, then you have to use a suitable value accordingly, however [8 may not be sufficient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation), depending on the user's actual configuration.

Comment: @questioner Yes.  The link SergeyA posted clearly shows that 260 is the right number for your program.  Of course you also have to make sure you have something like `char lpBuffer[260]` somewhere.  (Or maybe `char lpBuffer[261]` to be on the safe side.)

Comment: If you pass a number less than the required buffer, it will not fill the buffer and will return the size needed. This is similar to many Windows API functions in that you can pass sometimes zero, sometimes null to a function (depends on function) and from the return value or a parameter pointer value, you can get the required size of the buffer. Read the remarks on the Return Value part of the documentation.

Comment: I like the answers, my only worry is this seems a bit "hacky" to purposely make a function fail, and then call it again. I thought we were behind the days of this, as it almost reminds me of the original xbox and the insanity programmers had to do due to the limited RAM available.

Comment: @questioner calling a function passing NULL in order to get the required length before calling again with an allocated buffer is common practice. Not hacky at all. Best practice in fact.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan arguably not **best**. For example, it forces one to use dynamic allocations on implementations not supporting variable length arrays.

Comment: It is best practice. Because it means you can be certain to succeed. Hard to get behind fixed length arrays if that means failure is possible. Dynamic allocation is pretty routine.